# countif multiple criteria and is included in a list

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have multiple sheets in a workbook in Google Sheets:

"Likes" includes submissions by a user (submitting user listed in Col B), on behalf of a student (student named in Col E).

"staff_roster" contains a list of staff in Col A who are approved to submit a 'like'.

"seventh" contains a student roster in Col A. I want to Col C to list the count of all 'likes' that were submitted only by an approved staff member.

That is, I'm trying to build a tally of submissions for each student that validates only those submissions by users inluded in the "staff_roster" sheet (see images of the three relevant sheets).

Thus far I've been trying to use COUNTIFS but I'm getting stuck in the "is the user who submitted included in the staff_roster sheet?" part. Using [this resource](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-check-if-cell-contains-text-from-list/) plus COUNTIFS, I tried

```
=COUNTIFS(Likes!$E$2:$E, $A4, Likes!$B$2:$B, ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(Likes!$B$2:$B), REGEXMATCH(Likes!$B$2:$B,".*(?i)("&TEXTJOIN("|",
TRUE,staff_roster!$A$2:$A)&").*") ,"")))
```

but it's not producing the correct answer. All help will be well received.[image: likes sheet][image: staff_roster sheet][image: seventh sheet]

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion

> Note: The formula is based on your provided image and may differ from your actual data.

You can alternately try this code utilizing `ROWS`,`QUERY` and `FILTER` to achieve your desired result.

### Sheet Formula:

```
=ROWS(QUERY(FILTER(Likes!A$2:G,COUNTIF(staff_roster!A$2:A,Likes!B$2:B)),"Select * where Col5 = '"&A2&"'"))
```

### Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### References:

[ROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en)

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en&sjid=8738523281119783295-AP)

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en-GB&sjid=8738523281119783295-AP)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.